# how to republished android app after rejected?

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-play-console

I published an android app and it rejected for violating the Permissions policy. Can I correct these issues and republished?

> Your recent app submission was rejected for violating the Permissions policy. Before submitting your app for another review, read through the policy and make sure your app is in compliance.

This is the only permission I used.

```
android.permission.SEND_SMS
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what your app does, but you are using a restricted permission, and Google started cracking down on apps using it a while back.

For a good reason: it is easy to abuse the ability to send SMS and steal money from users.

If you can remove the permission and any code that relies on it, this would be the simplest solution for you.

If not, read [these instructions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303) and see if you can convince Google that your app legitimately needs this capability.